# drawing two curves in the same figure

Tags: graphics, graphs

Please i need someone who can help me to draw two curves into one figure. I need to draw the two curves Y1 and Y2 in the same figure.

[image]

By the way, i tried to write the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1.5);

 \draw[thick, color=red] plot [smooth,tension=0] coordinates{(0.1, 0.003) (0.5, 0.005) (2, 0.4) (5, 1)};
 \draw[thick, color=red] plot [smooth,tension=0] coordinates{(0.1, 0.2) (0.5, 0.5) (2, 0.1) (5, 1.4)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that i get a very small graph especially a very small y-axis!! so how can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing what you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. Have you tried using the `pfgplotstable` package?

Comment: ah okk,  thank you so much for your response anyway, i will delete my question and post another one with some codes :)

Comment: Don't delete it. Simply edit and improve it.

Comment: ah ok i will :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use additionaly the `pgfplots` package.

The first way is using the coordinates directly in the code to produce the graphic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left]
            \addplot[mark=none,red,thick] coordinates {(0.1, 0.003) (0.5, 0.005) (2, 0.4) (5, 1)};
            \addplot[mark=none,red,thick] coordinates {(0.1, 0.2) (0.5, 0.5) (2, 0.1) (5, 1.4)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The second way is use a table, from a `.dat` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left]
            \addplot[mark=none,red,thick] table[x=x,y=y1] {table.dat};
            \addplot[mark=none,red,thick] table[x=x,y=y2] {table.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `table.dat` file is a text document (you can create it with notepad), and the data is written inside it, in columns, like this:

```
x   y1  y2
0.1 0.003   0.2
0.5 0.005   0.5
2   0.4 0.1
5   1   1.4
```

Every data is tab-separated.

Both schemes produce this:

[image]

In addition, you can describe a legend and labels for both axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            xlabel=$X$,
            ylabel=$Y$,
            legend pos= south east]
            \addplot[mark=none,blue,thick] table[x=x,y=y1] {table.dat};
            \addplot[mark=none,red,thick] table[x=x,y=y2] {table.dat};
            \legend{$Y_1$,$Y_2$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Sincerely, i don't know how to thank you Dear!! thank you sooooo much

Answer (score 5):

Alternative option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {$x$}; % x-axis
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$}; % y-axis
        \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,5}
            \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,1pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below] {$\x$};
        \foreach \y in {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5}
            \draw[yshift=\y cm] (1pt,0pt) -- (-1pt,0pt) node[left] {$\y$};
 \draw[thick, color=red] plot [smooth,tension=0] coordinates{(0.1, 0.003) (0.5, 0.005) (2, 0.4) (5, 1)} node[right, color=black] {$Y_1$};
 \draw[thick, color=blue] plot [smooth,tension=0] coordinates{(0.1, 0.2) (0.5, 0.5) (2, 0.1) (5, 1.4)} node[right, color=black] {$Y_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The following changes the plotting scale.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1.5);

 \draw[thick, color=red] plot [smooth,tension=0] coordinates{(0.1, 0.003) (0.5, 0.005) (2, 0.4) (5, 1)};
 \draw[thick, color=red] plot [smooth,tension=0] coordinates{(0.1, 0.2) (0.5, 0.5) (2, 0.1) (5, 1.4)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip3ex
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm,y=2.0cm]

    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1.5);

 \draw[thick, color=red] plot [smooth,tension=0] coordinates{(0.1, 0.003) (0.5, 0.005) (2, 0.4) (5, 1)};
 \draw[thick, color=red] plot [smooth,tension=0] coordinates{(0.1, 0.2) (0.5, 0.5) (2, 0.1) (5, 1.4)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply :) i really appreciated it :)