# Change the forms of curves to distinguish between them

Tags: graphics, graphs

If we assume 2 curves in the same figure. So to distinguish between them, we set a different colors for them. However, can we change the form not the color ? In other words, if we assume that we have 5 curves, and to distinguish between them, we set a specific form for each of them.
Any help?

By the way, you can read the code below (taken from this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144147/drawing-two-curves-in-the-same-figure)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            xlabel=$X$,
            ylabel=$Y$,
            legend pos= south east]
            \addplot[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(0.1, 0.003) (0.5, 0.005) (2, 0.4) (5, 1)};
            \addplot[mark=none,red,thick] coordinates {(0.1, 0.2) (0.5, 0.5) (2, 0.1) (5, 1.4)};
            \legend{$Y_1$,$Y_2$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You mean for example one solid line and one dashed line?

Comment: Exactly! one solid line, one dashed line, one with other form.. i need at least 4 or 5 forms :) Thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several line styles available in `pgfplots`. The default is a solid line, other options include `dashed`, `dotted`, `dashdotted`, and dense and loose versions of the same, e.g. `densely dashed` and `loosely dashed`. See section **4.7.2 Line Styles** of the `pgfplots` manual.

You can also specify your own pattern with `dash pattern`, for example `dash pattern=on 10pt off 2pt on 5pt off 6pt`.

Add these to the options of the `\addplot`, just like the colours. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            xlabel=$X$,
            ylabel=$Y$,
            legend pos=north west]
            \addplot[mark=none,solid,thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0.5)};
            \addplot[mark=none,dashed,thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
            \addplot[mark=none,dotted,thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1.5)};
            \addplot[mark=none,dashdotted,thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,2)};
            \addplot[mark=none,dash pattern=on 10pt off 2pt on 5pt off 6pt,thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,2.5)};
            \legend{$Y_1$,$Y_2$,$Y_3$,$Y_4$,$Y_5$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! do you know one more form ? i need only one more form :) thank's in advance!

Comment: @Liszt I added a custom one, but as I mention there are `densely dashed`/`densely dotted` etc. as well.